# cs-cart The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: cs-cart

### I Install cs-cart MULTIVENDOR 4.3.3 with demo data, the admin page is working fine but in main page or store front most of the like are not working, I keep getting like this error message

The requested URL /cs-cart/profiles-add/ was not found on this server.
The requested URL /cs-cart/acme-corp/ was not found on this server.

### The requested URL /cs-cart/electronics/ was not found on this server.

I'm using Apache/2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 and php 5.5.9-1

could any one help me regarding this problem

Best 
Salim Hussein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is caused the SEO module. Please open the .htaccess file and replace:

```
# RewriteBase /
```

with

```
RewriteBase /cs-cart
```

If it does not help, change the status of the SEO module to Disabled and check the result

Comment: Disabling the SEO module did the trick. So basically this module will only work if i host my site directly under my html root dir right? not if its under a sub dir.

Comment: No, you can use your CS-Cart installation in subdirectory. Please do the following:

- correct .htaccess according to the previous message
- open the config.local.php file and correct the https_path and http_path parameters
- go to Administration -> Stores page and specify correct URLs for the store-front